# How to install Socrata platform

Tags: socrata

I am trying to install the Socrata platform, to implement a prototipe that demonstrate the potentiality of this platform. However, i would like to know how i can setup
Socrata platform. In particular, how can i connect together all the modules? I already downloaded the modules, i have executed the sbt, compile and run command, but i have received the following error: "No main class detected". For example, i don't know how i could launch the data coordinator module. How can i resolve this problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The "Socrata Platform" refers to the software infrastructure on top of which Socrata delivers its Software-as-a-Service products (http://www.socrata.com/products/) so my guess is that you actually mean the Socrata Open Data Server (http://open-source.socrata.com/).

Open Data Server is still a work in progress, and better deployment documentation will be provided as we near a full production launch on our SaaS platform as well. We'll make an announcement when that is available.

Do you mind sharing a little more information about what you're looking to prototype? Perhaps we can help.